# SQL Update and Replace

Tags: sql

Can someone guide me in the right direction.  I'm trying do an update and replace on a column in a database.  This is the SQL code that I am using (SQL 2008 Express Edition).

```
*update GameList set image = replace(Image, 'NintendoDS', 'Nintendo DS') WHERE Image LIKE '%NintendoDS%'*
```

*Image*
 
/webimages/NintendoDS/boxmonstersvsaliens.jpg

**This is the error I am getting:**

*String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is there is a row where adding the extra space (or spaces if the test string is repeated) would make the resulting string bigger than the column size.

For example if the column is declared varchar(20) you are trying to add a string of size 21

Comment: Go figure.  String of binary data would be truncated spells it out!  Thanks.  Helped me find a looming problem!

Comment: Glad to help.  As a side note: Because of how SQL works in the latest version varchar(max) should have no performance hit over varchar(x), it is only useful if somewhere else in the system there is a requirement to keep strings at size x

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind.  First is that your column is not long enough; however I suspect that's not the case and this will be fixed by using:

```
update GameList set image = rtrim(replace(Image, 'NintendoDS', 'Nintendo DS')) 
WHERE Image LIKE '%NintendoDS%'
```

If your column is padded with trailing blanks, then the original replace will fail because adding the extra space exceeds the maximum column length.  R-Trimming the result prevents this problem.

Comment: This is also an issue I was having.  Too many blank spaces to the right.  RTRIM will be in my coding in the future!  Thanks!